# Archivos js no se actualizan en el servidor cache

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, servidor, cache

hola tengo un proyecto en laravel 5, mi problema es que subi unas cambios hechos en local a mi servidor compartido y ahora no se ven, no actualiza los archivos js en cache, he hecho uso de:

```
Route::get('/cache', function() {
    //probe esto primero
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('view:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('key:generate');
});
```

he borrado cache de mi navegador, probado en varios diferentes y nada parece funcionar, escribo acá porque de verdad me parece insólito lo que pasa. Alguna idea?

Revisando el phpinfo del servidor. Me encontré con esto, tendrá algo que ver?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Son archivos de JS compilados? de ser así, ¿haces la compilación en el servidor remoto o en tu máquina?, ¿usas Mix para la compilación o para el versionado de los archivos?

Comment: hola, gracias por la respuesta, pero no comprendo bien a que se refiere, son archivos .js nada extraordinario, los uso para agregar ajax y algunas funciones en mis plantillas de blade es todo, el problema  acá es que yo miro por ftp el archivo y tiene todos los cambios que hice pero al cargar el navegador se ve el anterior, como dije he borrado cache repetidas veces, tanto en mi laravel como en el navegador y sigue igual

Answer (score 0):

Lo que haces es correcto, asi se debe de vaciar la cache del navegador,

1. Control + F5
2. Comandos de Cache Laravel
3. Cuando subes un .zip, me ha paso que cuando descomprimo asi los archivos esten actualizados no se reflejan los cambios, lo que yo he hecho es despues de subir los cambios ingreso al cpane, al administrador de archivos y edito un solo archivo, le agrego un espacio o lo que sea e inmediatamente refleja todos los cambios